# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen from Ruby gem writing to filesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-permissions, axlsx

Ruby 2.4.0

Rails 5.2.3

I have a Rails ActiveJob generating an xlsx report using the Axlsx gem. When it tries to write the file to the file system with:

`axlsx.serialize("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@report_name}.xlsx")`

It gives the following error: `Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/storage/my_app/releases/20200610141310/tmp/report_for_call_25_20200610142531.xlsx)`

Full trace:

```
E, [2020-06-10T14:25:31.090477 #23375] ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [GenerateReportJob] [013852d1-8127-4db4-90ae-895c998f34c7] Error performing GenerateReportJob (Job ID: 013852d1-8127-4db4-90ae-895c998f34c7) from Async(default) in 30.2ms: 
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/storage/my_app/releases/20200610141310/tmp/report_for_call_25_20200610142531.xlsx):
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/zip/output_stream.rb:36:in `initialize'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/zip/output_stream.rb:36:in `new'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/zip/output_stream.rb:36:in `initialize'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/zip/output_stream.rb:52:in `new'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/zip/output_stream.rb:52:in `open'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/axlsx-2891eb2246d9/lib/axlsx/package.rb:104:in `serialize'
/var/storage/my_app/releases/20200610141310/lib/my_app/generate_xml_report.rb:87:in `create_excel'
/var/storage/my_app/releases/20200610141310/lib/my_app/generate_xml_report.rb:59:in `generate_report'
/var/storage/my_app/releases/20200610141310/app/jobs/generate_report_job.rb:6:in `perform'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:39:in `block in perform_now'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/releases/20200610141310/app/jobs/generate_report_job.rb:23:in `around_report_job'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/i18n-1.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:297:in `with_locale'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in '
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in '
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in '
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `block in tag_logger'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `tag_logger'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in '
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:38:in `perform_now'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:24:in `block in execute'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in '
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in '
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activejob-5.2.3/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb:70:in `perform'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:348:in `run_task'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `loop'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `catch'
/var/storage/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'
```

The Rails app runs under the user 'app'.

The permissions on the tmp folder are: `lrwxrwxrwx  1 app app`

I also have a development server running basically the exact setup and this issue is not happening.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: This is likely not a Ruby issue, but one of the operating system. What happens if you do a `system("touch "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@report_name}.xlsx")` before serializing?

Comment: I tried what you said and it seems like the system command cannot touch a new file into Rails.root/tmp, if I run the same command from the rails console it can touch a new file without problem, from my activejob however it does not work. HOWEVER, when touching from my activejob into /tmp, it does work!

Comment: And in both cases, the effective uid is the same? In any case, this now seems to be more suitable a question for [superuser](https://superuser.com/) as it is not related to RoR anymore. Not sure about this, but: You showed that the permissions to the `app` directory are 0777. Maybe you need permissions for the parent directories too? Also, it would not harm if you tell us which OS you are using (Linux, AIX, BSD, ...). And, the filesystem for the xlsx file is **only** used by your OS, and not (by chance) also by some Windows machine?

Comment: Did you fix this issue @user1934428 ?

I am experiencing pretty much the same error as the one you described...

`Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - storage/uploads/spreadsheets/RackMultipartetcetc.xlsx`